# Цикл после первого элемента перестает работать

Tags: python, for, set

Проблема состоит в том, что в строках 12 и 13

```
for key in DATABASE:
    print(f"{key}")
```

должен происходить перебор, но происходит так, что цикл затрагивает только первый элемент словаря и останавливается. Не могу разобраться, как починить данную ошибку

```
DATABASE = {
'Серёга': 'Омск',
'Соня': 'Москва',
'Миша': 'Москва',
'Дима': 'Челябинск',
'Алина': 'Красноярск',
'Егор': 'Пермь',
'Коля': 'Красноярск'
}  
def process_friend(name, query):
    for key in DATABASE:
        print(f"{key}")
        if key==name:
            if query == 'ты где?':
                return f"{name} в городе {DATABASE['name']}"
            else:
                return  '<неизвестный запрос>'
        else:
            return f'У тебя нет друга по имени {name}'
def process_query(query):
    n = query.split(', ') 
    if n[0] == 'Анфиса':
        return process_anfisa(n[1])
    else:
        print(n[0])
        return process_friend(n[0], n[1])
print(process_query('Соня, ты где?'))
```

Comment: И правильно делает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем цикле

```
for key in DATABASE:
```

команды `if`-`else`, но всякая ветвь в них окончатся командой `return`.

Команда `return` возвращает в ней указанное значение, а затем **немедленно окончит вызов функции `process_friend()`**, значит, другой переход циклом уже не совершится.

---

Когда вместо `return` вы примените вызов функции `print()`, ваш цикл будет продолжаться:

```
def process_friend(name, query):
    for key in DATABASE:
        print(f"{key = }")
        if key==name:
            if query == 'ты где?':
                print(f"{name} в городе {DATABASE[name]}")        # не DATABASE['name']
            else:
                print('<неизвестный запрос>')
        else:
            print(f'У тебя нет друга по имени {name}')
```

(Я в вашем коде исправил еще одну ошибку. :-))

---

*Примечание:*

Теперь, когда вы увидели, что ваш цикл уже работает, вы, наверно, хотите **после** каждого такого вызова `print()` добавить команду `return`:

```
        if query == 'ты где?':
            print(f"{name} в городе {DATABASE[name]}")
            return
        else:
            print('<неизвестный запрос>')
            return
    else:
        print(f'У тебя нет друга по имени {name}')
        return
```

Comment: значит я никак не могу продолжить цикл используя  return, даже если добавить в код  continue, pass

Comment: После команды `return` уже ничего в коде функции не выполнится, ни `continue`.

Comment: Есть такая команда `yield` («передать»), которая -  в отличие от команды `return` - как бы возвращает в ней показанное значение, но не окончает работу функции, а только ее приостановит. Но это уже достаточно сложная работа, какая-то другая функция должна на предоставленное значение ждать, и т.д., затем вам не рекомендую заниматься тем.

Answer (score -1):

```
DATABASE = {
    'Серёга': 'Омск',
    'Соня': 'Москва',
    'Миша': 'Москва',
    'Дима': 'Челябинск',
    'Алина': 'Красноярск',
    'Егор': 'Пермь',
    'Коля': 'Красноярск'
}
def process_friend(name, query):
    for key in DATABASE:
        if key == name:
            if query == 'ты где?':
                return f"{name} в городе {DATABASE[name]}"
            else:
                return '<неизвестный запрос>'
    else:
        return f'У тебя нет друга по имени {name}'

def process_query(query):
    n = query.split(', ')
    if n[0] == 'Анфиса':
        # Здесь может быть логика для обработки запроса для Анфисы
        pass
    else:
        return process_friend(n[0], n[1])

    print(process_query('Соня, ты где?'))
```

Вот ваш новый код, попробуйте

Comment: "Спасибо" вам. 1 код уже дал другой участник. 2. Вы не объяснили, где ошибка. 3. Объясните, чем лучше *этот* код авторского